# Deleting misspelled tags

Tags: support, tags

How can tags that are misspelled be deleted? There is a tag [plagarism](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagarism) as well as the correctly spelled [plagiarism](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism). It seems setting the misspelled as synonymous would not be a useful way out.

Comment: Update: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5056/68109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting here is exactly what you should do. I just [set up a synonym](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/plagiarism/synonyms) so that anyone who uses the misspelling will automatically have it corrected. Do note that if it's an uncommon issue you can just correct the tag yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit confused when I could not suggest it myself (because the mispelled did not have enouh uses, as I understood it).

Comment: @PeterJansson - Super Sekrit Mod Powers™ strike again!

Comment: @Peter: note that if a tag isn't heavily used, you can just edit it out - the system deletes unusued tags once a day.

Comment: Can someone do the same for "united-kindom"?

Comment: @Stuart - that's a one-off misspelling, rather than a common misspelling. Those are corrected by simply correcting the tag. Tag aliases are intended to correct common misspellings and identify true aliases; in the case of one-offs, it's easier just to fix the offending tag.

Comment: no, it's been used several times and has an attached wiki, and bizarrely no one is using the correct spelling. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kindom?sort=newest&pagesize=15

Comment: @Stuart - So weird. Anyway, fixed.