# Delete misspelled tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Resulting from a discussion on [this tag-related question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/tag-synonym-suggestions-for-redundant-tags?cb=1) I propose the deletion of several misspelled tag synonyms:

| Tag | Misspelled Synonym |
| --- | --- |
| [undergraduate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate) | [undergradute](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergradute) |
| [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship) | [autorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autorship) |
| [etiquette](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) | [etiquitte](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquitte) |
| [plagiarism](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagiarism) | [plagarism](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagarism) |

Please add if there are any more.

Reasons that speak for the deletion:

- It [has been discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it/71129#71129) and the outcome was to delete misspelled synonyms
- When entering tabs for a questions, there are suggested tabs appearing as soon as you start typing, so users don't have to know the correct spelling

Comment: My preference is to delete them. A UI change (gasp) could show tags with only one question in a different background color so that they are easy for the vigilant (looking at you GoodDeeds) to update. There is enough activity here to make that possible, I think.

Comment: A related issue is that of tags that only mark a single closed question. There is little use for such tags and they tend not to have associated wiki with them anyway. I've removed the tags from a couple of questions and may do more, but that brings the question to the head of the queue. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Buffy Tags are by default sorted based on the number of questions they are applied to, so I think it is straightforward to find tags applied on only one question. Also, the number of such tags is very small (five right now, was seven a few minutes ago before you removed two of them :)). Out of those, only one of them is on a closed question, and I don't think that specific tag in itself needs to necessarily be removed.

Comment: I removed the rest on closed question. I left Thailand which is on an open question and a bit of wiki is there. Country tags are probably valuable even if there are only a small number of questions. One question I retagged was closed with two unique tags. Tag visa was adequate for the question.

Comment: The only tags I removed from questions were on closed questions.

Comment: @Buffy I agree with the retag and your reasoning, I did not mean to imply that it was incorrectly done. Thanks for doing them.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, no worries. I was just explaining what I did in case some mod wanders in here.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Sursula and GoodDeeds, this has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!